# Go: Named type assertions and conversions

Tags: go

If I have a custom type that simply redefines a pre-defined type with a name:

```
type Answer string
```

And I try to use it in a function that accepts the pre-defined type:

```
func acceptMe(str string) {
    fmt.Println(str)
}

func main() {
    type Answer string
    var ans Answer = "hello"

    // cannot use ans (type Answer) as type string in function argument
    acceptMe(ans)          
    // invalid type assertion: ans.(string) (non-interface type Answer on left)
    acceptMe(ans.(string)) 
    // Does work, but I don't understand why if the previous doesn't:
    acceptMe(string(ans))
}
```

Why does the type assertion fail, but the conversion work?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Type assertion works for interfaces only. Interface can have arbitrary underlying type, so we have type assertion and type switch to the rescue. Type assertion returns `bool` as the second return value to indicate if assertion was successful.

Your custom type `Answer` can have only one underlying type. You already know the exact type - `Answer` and the underlying type - `string`. You don't need assertions, since conversion to the underlying type will always be successful.

### Old answer:

Just convert your custom type to `string`. The conversion will succeed since your custom type has `string` as an underlying type. The conversion syntax: string(ans). [Go Play](http://play.golang.org/p/yr1KkE4LVJ)

Comment: Thanks, while you were answering the question I discovered this, too. I'd like to know why that is the case.

Comment: Ups :) Updated the answer.

> // Does work, but I don't understand why if the previous doesn't.

Type assertion and type conversion are orthogonal things. Type assertion is for interfaces only.