# Why a type assertion works in one case, not in another?

Tags: go

Here is the problematic source code:

http://play.golang.org/p/lcN4Osdkgs

```
package main
import(
    "net/url"
    "io"
    "strings"
) 

func main(){
    v := url.Values{"key": {"Value"}, "id": {"123"}}
    body := strings.NewReader(v.Encode())
    _ = proxy(body)
    // this work 

    //invalid type assertion: body.(io.ReadCloser) (non-interface type *strings.Reader on left)
    _, _ = body.(io.ReadCloser)

}

func proxy( body io.Reader) error{
    _, _ = body.(io.ReadCloser)
    return  nil
}
```

Can someone tell me why this code wont work ?

The error occur here:

```
body := strings.NewReader(v.Encode())

rc, ok := body.(io.ReadCloser)

// invalid type assertion: body.(io.ReadCloser) (non-interface type *strings.Reader on left)
```

However `proxy(body io.Reader)` do the same thing but have no error. Why?

http://play.golang.org/p/CWd-zMlrAZ

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are dealing with two different `Reader`:

- [strings.NewReader()](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#NewReader) returns a [`strings.Reader`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Reader), which isn't an interface.
  But since it implements `io.Reader`, you can pass it to `proxy()`.
- `proxy()` takes an [`io.Reader`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader), which is an interface.

For non-interface types, the dynamic type is always the static type.
A [type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#TypeAssertion) works for interfaces only, which can have arbitrary underlying type.
(see [my answer on interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23148998/6309), and "[Go: Named type assertions and conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18692017/6309)")

Comment: Thanks!! , your comment really help me understand a lot about interface (from 0 to enough ) .
I modified my code so it will work [http://play.golang.org/p/C4tA2Xaq4p](http://play.golang.org/p/C4tA2Xaq4p).
I have to convert strings.Reader to interface before doing any type assertion.