# Go: Type assertions on structs?

Tags: go

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Number int

func (n *Number) IncreaseMe(i int) {
        *n += i
}

func main() {
        n := Number(10)

        n.IncreaseMe(90) // n is now supposed to be 100

        fmt.Println(n)
}
```

When running the code above, it gives me the error message

> invalid operation: *n += i (mismatched types Number and int)

Which is to be expected as it's trying to do a math operation on variables which don't share the same type.

I then tried

```
*n.(int) += i
```

which tells the compiler not to worry as *n can be safely treated as an integer, which leads me to

```
invalid type assertion: n.(int) (non-interface type *Number on left)
```

I believe this is happening because type assertions works only with interfaces, not custom types.

So what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in "[Go: Named type assertions and conversions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18691927/6309)"

> Type assertion works for interfaces only. Interface can have arbitrary underlying type, so we have type assertion and type switch to the rescue.

You don't need type assertion: you can just:

- convert `*n` to an `int`: `int(*n)` (since you know full well the actual type).
- make the addition
- convert back to `Number`

  ```
  *n = Number(int(*n) + i)
  ```

See this [<kbd>play.golang.org</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/1CRRy68GNG): the output is 100.

---

As [ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714266/go-type-assertions-on-structs#comment40197139_25714293):

> Go splits the concept of "casting" into two separate concepts:
>
> - one ("type conversions") for conversions that the compiler knows are correct, and
> - one ("type assertions") for conversions that must be checked at runtime.
>
> The latter only applies to interfaces, since only interfaces have additional type information at runtime that that's not known at compile time.

Comment: +1. In other words, Go splits the concept of "casting" into two separate concepts: one ("type conversions") for conversions that the compiler knows are correct, and one ("type assertions") for conversions that must be checked at runtime. The latter only applies to interfaces, since only interfaces have additional type information at runtime that that's not known at compile time.

Comment: @ruakh good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: (@ruakh, love the description; had never heard it put that way)